# Artifactory repo folder structure not as expected when deploying files

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I created a generic repo in Artifactory which I want to deploy my artifacts to.
I'm trying to setup a simple-layout folder structure such as:
[image]
I can get this structure only if i'll deploy couple of sub folders.

When deploying I get in Artifactory this structure:
[image]

Which is anyoing because I set properties on the build_definition_name level
 which I want to read and write to but they are not visible as it now points to
 the version folder.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifactory by default compresses empty folders in the UI.
You can disable it easily by unchecking the following: [image: Example]